# What happens if you put a bag of holding in a bag of holding while being in the astral plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes, astral

I know that putting a bag of holding in a bag of holding destroys both and creates a portal to the astral plane, but what would happen if a player chooses to put a bag of holding in a back of holding while being in the astral plane?

Would nothing happen? Would you be transported to a realm of chaos? Any answers would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I've closed this question as duplicate since is has already been answered. This isn't a bad thing, duplicates help others find the answer with a broader search terms. If you don't think this is a duplicate you can [edit] this question to explain how it is different. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Welcome to the Double Astral Plane.